# Limit the length of a string using angular 2/ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

How do i restrict the phone number field to 10 characters using angular2.
i tried using **ng-maxlenth** but it is working only in browser but not in the android devices.

I found one code snippet using angular 1. But how do i rewrite the the same code using angular2?

```
app.directive("limitTo", [function() {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
            var limit = parseInt(attrs.limitTo);
            angular.element(elem).on("keypress", function(e) {
                if (this.value.length == limit) e.preventDefault();
            });
        }
    }
}]);

<input limit-to="4" type="number" class="form-control input-lg" ng-model="search.main" placeholder="enter first 4 digits: 09XX">
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In angular2 it will look like:

```typescript
@Directive({
  selector: '[limit-to]',
  host: {
    '(keypress)': '_onKeypress($event)',
  }
})
export class LimitToDirective {
  @Input('limit-to') limitTo; 
  _onKeypress(e) {
     const limit = +this.limitTo;
     if (e.target.value.length === limit) e.preventDefault();
  }
}
```

Don't forget to register directive in `NgModule` sth like:

```typescript
@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, LimitToDirective ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

And then use it like:

```typescript
<input limit-to="4" type="number" placeholder="enter first 4 digits: 09XX">
```

Here is the **[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/sgMubU0p8Z5BPzAIKsf4?p=preview)**!

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using a custom directive, you could just use the `maxlength` HTML attribute and the attr binding from Angular 2 like this: `[attr.maxlength]="4"`

```
<ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="a.myInput" [attr.maxlength]="4"></ion-input>
```

You can also bind that attribute to a property from your Component to set the max length dynamically.

Comment: This is the cleaner answer imo

Comment: where is this plunker?

Comment: I've updated the plunker @Ortiz, now it's working again :)

Comment: thank you, I will try this out at my project and let you know if worked.

Comment: Glad to help @JoãoPauloAmorim :)

Comment: It is also good solution for reactive forms to separate validators from 
input restrictions. 
By this way you can use restriction for input by this attribute without custom directive, and at the same time you can add separate validator to appropriate formControl in ..component.ts:

`myInput: new FormControl(null, [ Validators.maxLength(4)])`

Comment: Thanks @Klyuch, that's indeed very useful :)

Answer (score 8):

Just use slice:

```
{{expression | slice:begin:end}}
```

Angular DOCS:
https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ajs-quick-reference.html

Comment: This works the best and is quite simple, just add in a condition for ellipsis and...   
{{ p.name.length >= 40 ? (p.name  | slice:0:40)+'...' : p.name }}

Comment: This works perfectly fine for my use case. Thanks +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the similar issue in ionic2/angular2 on samsung android devices.
I have written the custom directive to handle this.
Same mentioned in my blog and usage instructions mentioned in that.
http://jagadeeshmanne.blogspot.com/2017/08/ionic-2-angular-maxlength-issue-in.html

```js
import { Directive, EventEmitter, HostListener, Input, Output } from '@angular/core';
import { Platform } from "ionic-angular";
 
@Directive({
    selector: '[cMaxLength]'
})
export class MaxLengthDirective {
 
  @Input('cMaxLength') cMaxLength:any;
  @Output() ngModelChange:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
 
  constructor(public platform: Platform) {
  }
 
  //keypress event doesn't work in ionic android. the keydown event will work but the value doesn't effect until this event has finished. hence using keyup event. 
  @HostListener('keyup',['$event']) onKeyup(event) {
    const element = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    const limit = this.cMaxLength;
    if (this.platform.is('android')) {
      const value = element.value.substr(0, limit);
      if (value.length <= limit) {
        element.value = value;
      } else {
        element.value = value.substr(0, limit-1);
      }
      this.ngModelChange.emit(element.value);
    }
  }
 
  @HostListener('focus',['$event']) onFocus(event) {
    const element = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
    if (!this.platform.is('android')) {
      element.setAttribute('maxlength', this.cMaxLength)
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@yurzui solution didn't work on android device. the keypress event does not fire for some reasons, as mentioned by @Jagadeesh. Also there are issues updating binded data by ngModel.

I suggest this solution instead:

```
import {Directive, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core'

@Directive({
  selector: '[limit-to]',
  host: {
    '(input)': 'onInputChange($event)',
  }
})
export class LimitToDirective {
  @Input('limit-to') limitTo;
  @Output() ngModelChange:EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
  oldValue: any;

  onInputChange(e){
    const limit = +this.limitTo;
    if(e.target.value.length > limit) {
      e.target.value = this.oldValue;
    }
    this.oldValue = e.target.value;
    this.ngModelChange.emit(e.target.value);
  }
}
```

on input event, check the length of the current input value, if it exceeded the limit, replace it by the last stored oldValue, then update the displayed text value of the input. and fire a new ngModelChange event to update the binded property.

Answer (score 0):

based on @yurzui angular 4/5 
more complete solution
min , max  attributes + bug fix for delete

```
import {Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, Input, OnInit, Renderer} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appMaxDigits]'
})
export class MaxDigitsDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input('appMaxDigits') appMaxDigits;
    constructor(private renderer: Renderer, private el: ElementRef) {}
    @HostListener('keydown', ['$event']) onKeydown(e: any) {
        const limit = +this.appMaxDigits;
        if (e.keyCode > 47 && e.keyCode < 127) {
            if (e.target.value.length === limit) { e.preventDefault(); }
        }
    }
    ngOnInit() {
        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'min', '0');
        this.renderer.setElementAttribute(this.el.nativeElement, 'max', '9'.repeat(this.appMaxDigits));
    }
}
```