# Limit the length of input field using angular2

Tags: angular

I have implemented the directive to restrict the input field using angular2. It is working fine in desktop browser, but not working in android mobile.

### component

```
import { LimitToDirective } from '../../../directives/limitedvalidation';
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/profile/change-basic-details/change-basic-details.html',
  directives: [LimitToDirective]  
})
export class UpdateBasicDetailsPage {
  constructor(){}
}
```

### directive

```
 import {Directive, Input} from '@angular/core'
    @Directive({
      selector: '[limit-to]',
      host: {
        '(keypress)': '_onKeypress($event)',
      }
    })
    export class LimitToDirective {
      @Input('limit-to') limitTo; 
      _onKeypress(e) {
         const limit = +this.limitTo;
         if (e.target.value.length === limit) e.preventDefault();
      }
    }
```

### template

```
<ion-input limit-to="12" type="tel" [formControl]="aadhaarno">
```

Answer (score 10):

Use maxlength as belows :

```
<ion-input [maxlength]="12" type="tel" [formControl]="aadhaarno">
```

Comment: i am getting error in android mobile,  [INFO:CONSOLE(463)] "Error: Uncaught (in promise): EXCEPTION: Error in build/pages/profile/change-basic-details/change-basic-details.html:63:8
 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: Invalid integer literal when parsing null in base 10

Comment: Oh 'cmon this only validates user input — it does not restrict user to enter more than 12 symbols in input field.

Answer (score 2):

you should use max-length html5 attribute and then use form validation for Angular2, no custom directive needed.

Comment: Oh 'cmon this only validates user input — it does not restrict user to enter more than 12 symbols in input field.

Comment: can't we go and change the maxlenght limit in browser , its not safe I suppose. We need to put some validation on javascript side as well

Comment: Attention, the HTML attribute is called `maxlength`, not `max-length`, and has existed long before HTML 5...

Answer (score 0):

Please refer

```
import { Directive, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
 selector: '[limit-to]',
 host: {
'(input)': 'onInputChange($event)',
}
})
export class LimitToDirective {
 @Input('limit-to') limitTo;
 @Output() ngModelChange: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();
 oldValue: any;

 onInputChange(e) {
debugger
const limit = +this.limitTo;
if (e.target.value.length > limit) {
  e.target.value = this.oldValue;
}
this.oldValue = e.target.value;
this.ngModelChange.emit(e.target.value);
}
}


<ion-input limit-to="12" type="tel" [formControl]="aadhaarno">
```

> [click](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45962854/7469332)