# Angular 2.0 restrict user from entering characters in input field

Tags: html, angularjs, angular

I have an input text box i would like to restrict the input to a fix number of characters, for example stop displaying keystrokes after this maximum length has been reached in Angular JS 2

Comment: Did you try maxlength?

Comment: HTML's maxlength is exactly for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit the length of input field using angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284869/limit-the-length-of-input-field-using-angular2)

Comment: Thank you guys html max length worked for me