# contenteditable -- How to make only the title to be in block using angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, contenteditable

I have a input field which is editable, when I click on that it must give background color as white with in box. Please help me.

I am sharing my code here:

**HTML**

```
<div id="section{{section.index}}">
    <h2 class="title" contenteditable="true" ng-model="section.title"
        onclick="document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)"
        ng-keydown="disable_enter($event)"
        ng-change="check_section_title($index)"
        maxlength="40">
    </h2>
</div>
```

**I am getting like this**

[image: I am getting like this]

**But i need like this **
[image: But i need Like this:]

Comment: do you want via jquery or angular js function this. are you try max-length of html or ng-maxlength for angular prospective

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40285086/7951676

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Limit the length of input field using angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284869/limit-the-length-of-input-field-using-angular2)

Comment: @user7951676 anglarjs is not angular2 !

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angularjs/info

https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular/info

Comment: The answer doesn't need any angular

Comment: @Ajay2707: Angularjs i need

Comment: @Tulsi Please find my answer and example below.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Content-Editable in the angular js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45570363/content-editable-in-the-angular-js/45579672#45579672).

Answer (score 0):

You should use `maxlength` to your input control instead of div or h1 tags.

Use something like this if you using angular version 1

```
<input type="text" ng-maxlength="40" />
```

Use something like this if you using angular2

```
<input type="text" [maxlength]="40" />
```

JS Code :

```js
document.getElementById("myInput").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
   function changeColor() { 
   var textBoxLength = document.getElementById('myInput').value.length;
  if(textBoxLength >= 5){
    document.getElementById("myInput").style.backgroundColor = "white";
  }    
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js">
  </script>
  <body ng-app="">
    <form name="myForm">
      <h1>Type in textbox</h1>
      <input name="myInput" id="myInput" ng-model="myInput" ng-maxlength="5" onkeypress="changeColor()">
      <h1 ng-if="!myForm.myInput.$valid">The value is too long</h1>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

In the above code, i am setting background to lightblue initially , and changing it to white while the characters go beyond 5. but in your case it should be 40.

Comment: i don have input textbox here.. in h2 tag only i must edit please help

Comment: for editing you must be having any input control right ?

Comment: ya but eevrything is happeneing with h2 only

Comment: What you are saying is correct but these are not supporting my requirement

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `ng-model` on h2 tag. You can use an input in conjunction with the h2 tag. Hide the h2 tag on click and enable the input. You can use `maxlength` to limit the characters to 40 and use `ng-maxlength` for validations

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.val={};
  $scope.val.type="Hello";
  $scope.contenteditable=false; 
  $scope.check_section_title = function() {
         $scope.contenteditable=!$scope.contenteditable;  
        };
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <form name="myForm" novalidate>
        <div style="padding: 10px">
        <div id="section{{section.index}}">
    <h2 class="title" ng-click="check_section_title()"  ng-if="!contenteditable">{{val.type}}</h2>
</div>
            <input name="Hazmat" ng-model="val.type" maxlength="40" ng-maxlength="40" required ng-if="contenteditable" ng-blur="check_section_title()">
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: this is matching my requiremenet, i need background color to be white

Comment: What do you mean by background color? You dont want any border on input?

Comment: Ya i need border to the editable text with white background color

Comment: The inputs background is white only. I am not understanding your requirement about white background. Can u be more specific?

Comment: no errors.. Actually my text box is with blue in color if i click on title for editing it must give white bg color and text must be limited to 40 characters

Comment: @Tulsi I have updated my answer with ng-class to make background of input white. Check if it is working now.

Comment: Why is your background blue? Maybe try using !important on white bg.

Answer (score 0):

Check this example which give you both your solution max length as well as color changing when textbox selected.

You can use `ng-maxlength="3"` as well as class to highlight the maxlength comes.

http://jsfiddle.net/gabrielmaldi/5o1uxnx8/

http://jsfiddle.net/ksevksev/YWq7g/

Comment: what happened, where are you stuck

Comment: it is not taking anything.. After giving all these also not working

Answer (score 0):

## Custom Directive for `contenteditable` elements

To make a `contenteditable` element work with the [ng-model directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModel)
 and the [ngModelController](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController):

```
 <div contenteditable
      name="myWidget" ng-model="userContent"
      strip-br="true"
      required>Change me!
 </div>
```

Create a [custom directive](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive):

```
  app.directive('contenteditable', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
      require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

        // Specify how UI should be updated
        ngModel.$render = function() {
          element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(ngModel.$viewValue || ''));
        };

        // Listen for change events to enable binding
        element.on('blur keyup change', function() {
          scope.$evalAsync(read);
        });
        read(); // initialize

        // Write data to the model
        function read() {
          var html = element.html();
          // When we clear the content editable the browser leaves a <br> behind
          // If strip-br attribute is provided then we strip this out
          if (attrs.stripBr && html === '<br>') {
            html = '';
          }
          ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
        }
      }
    };
  }]);
```

## [The DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/dmtljRLPtvdEuNpkjZsX?p=preview)

```js
angular.module('app', ['ngSanitize'])
.directive('contenteditable', ['$sce', function($sce) {
    return {
      restrict: 'A', // only activate on element attribute
      require: '?ngModel', // get a hold of NgModelController
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
        if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

        // Specify how UI should be updated
        ngModel.$render = function() {
          element.html($sce.getTrustedHtml(ngModel.$viewValue || ''));
        };

        // Listen for change events to enable binding
        element.on('blur keyup change', function() {
          scope.$evalAsync(read);
        });
        read(); // initialize

        // Write data to the model
        function read() {
          var html = element.html();
          // When we clear the content editable the browser leaves a <br> behind
          // If strip-br attribute is provided then we strip this out
          if (attrs.stripBr && html === '<br>') {
            html = '';
          }
          ngModel.$setViewValue(html);
        }
      }
    };
}])
```

```html
  <script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <script src="//unpkg.com/angular-sanitize/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<body ng-app="app">
  <form name="myForm">
 <p>Click on below div to edit</p>
 <div contenteditable
      name="myWidget" ng-model="userContent"
      strip-br="true"
      required>Change me!</div>
  <span ng-show="myForm.myWidget.$error.required">Required!</span>
 <hr>
 <textarea ng-model="userContent" aria-label="Dynamic textarea"></textarea>
</form>
</body>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS ngModelController API Reference - Custom Control Example](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/ngModel.NgModelController#custom-control-example)