# How to restrict the number of characters user can enter in ion-textarea in Ionic 2

Tags: css, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a text area in my Ionic 2 App, where I want to restrict the user to give comments of only less than 500 characters. How can I achieve it in Ionic 2?

Comment: can check http://stackoverflow.com/a/39848327/5868331

Comment: or can use https://github.com/yuyang041060120/ng2-validation readymade validations

Comment: Check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39361721/limit-the-length-of-a-string-using-angular-2-ionic-2

Answer (score 1):

Try with `maxlength=500` in your inputfield.